# Bootstrap Datapicker - Calendar Ubication grid column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar

I have a web app, and I based it on this calendar example:
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

I always show the calendar and I don't need the input box input.  So I hide it. My problem, is the calendar ubication. I need to show calendar, on my grid column bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      here my calendar
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      other content
   </div>
</div>
```

How I can do it?

Comment: I resolved the problem in this web:
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem in this web:
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Thanks,